# Propositional Logic - Resolution properties

Tags: math, youtube, logic, theorem-proving

I was watching a video on youtube about resolution and came across this video which helped me out quite a bit:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhTxW5c3BXo

Near the end, he does an example where the X's both on the opposite sides in each respective clause cancels out and the rest are joined together which is okay, but I was wanting to know if it workked for multiple variables cancelling out for example:

(AB -> CDXY)  (PQXY - > RS)

Cancelling XY would give ABPQ -> RSCD

I get this gut feeling that this case of "double resolution" doesn't apply and I haven't been able to find any information concerning the cancellation of 2 or more variables.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd to me to call this "cancelling out" but yes, the XY in your example acts in the way you are hoping for.

Please don't fall into the trap of just manipulating symbols algebraically. If you're going to learn this stuff you have to be able to think about what all those symbols *mean*. In this case, what you are asking is this ...

```
Given that (A&B) implies (C&D&X&Y)
and that (P&Q&X&Y) implies (R&S)
can you deduce that (A&B&P&Q) implies (R&S&C&D)?
```

Can you see that (A&B) must imply (C&D) and that (A&B) must also imply (X&Y)?
And that when you add (P&Q) to the mix there is an inference chain from (A&B) to (X&Y) and on to (R&S)?

It's not that one reference to XY cancels out another reference to XY, but that XY acts as a stepping stone in a similar way to what M does in the argument L->M, M->N, therefore L->N.

Another way of considering it is about naming. X and Y represent some truth-functional proposition. Who decided one should be called X and the other Y? There is no reason we could not just put the two propositions together as a single conjunction and call it Z. So then your two premises contain a single variable Z rather than the compound XY. And that Z can be "cancelled" if you want to think of it that way.

Comment: You've actually implied here that things work out *differently* than what user412255 expected.  You've implied that cancelling yields that "(A&B&P&Q) implies (R&S&C&D)", which he didn't think would happen.  Also, it does work out that one "XY" "cancels out", "annihilates", or "clashses with", or "resolves" with the other "XY" on the other side.  In the argument L->M, M->N, therefore  L->N when using resolution, we have (L->M) abbreviating (~ L v M), M->N abbreviating (~ M v N).  Then "M" clashes with "~M" resolving to (~L v N) which we abbreviate as (L->N).